# How to use env variables in package json or the other way around

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have just created my first React app but at the end I noticed that I am repeating myself in one place. I needed to add the `homepage` field to package.json since I am hosting my app under a sub-directory. But then I also needed to add the same homepage as the `basename` for my router. Well, that means I could update one and forget to update the other, it's not DRY.

Is there a way to have my homepage path only in one place? Maybe use the .env variable in package.json?

my `package.json` *(notice homepage)*

```
{
  "name": "react-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "/react-app/build",  
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
```

and also in my .env file

```
REACT_APP_HOMEPAGE=/react-app/build
```

Then in my router I needed to add this

```
<Router basename={process.env.REACT_APP_HOMEPAGE}>
```

Having my homepage path in 2 places is not a good idea. Is there a way I can use my ENV variable in the package.json file or maybe use the package.json variable in my app?

Comment: If you are using create-react-app, you need to prepend REACT_APP to get value.
If you have custom webpack configuration, you need to mention about HOMEPAGE there.

Comment: yes, I will update that but I am still repeating myself...

Comment: You initialized project using create-react-app or manual configuration?

Comment: I used ````npx create-react-app```` and I am using ````REACT_APP_HOMEPAGE```` in my .env

Comment: Generally, for best practice, the package.json file is meant to hold the list of dependencies both development or production ones and some configurations. Making it read from an environmental file is going against its purpose but your questions if a very valid one though.

Comment: @harisu but what is the solution then to avoid having my path in two places?

Comment: let me draft a suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I already mentioned in the comment section. Its not an ideal way of doing things but the below solution should work.
You should instead define the homepage in your package.json as you did then in the component that uses the router, you can import the package.json and read the homepage property from it.
as in

```
    let packageJson = require('../path/to/package.json');
    packageJson.homepage
```

If you later inside the package.json needs to use that value, you can then do something like

```
$npm_package_homepage.
```

you can find more details about using variables in package.json here
[Referencing variables in package.json](http://teamnik.org/referencing-values-in-package-json-as-variables/)
This way when there is a need for editing you can do it in one place inside the package.json and all the other places will take effect.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work. Although, it does seem strange that we need to pull in the ````package.json```` into our app like that.